# bicolour LED voltage threshold switch

Tags: transistors, zener

I'm a long time reader of this site but my first time as a poster.

In my scenario I am using a 6V AAA powerbank and want to have a simple indicator to tell me if the batteries are nearly flat say at a 5V level.

I'm looking to make a circuit that when I press a switch a bi-colour led lights up green if the voltage is above the set level, say 5V and red if it is below that value.

I found [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130999/low-battery-level-circuit-changing-trigger-level) that was close to what I am trying to achieve, but I couldn't quite work out how to arrange the transistors for a bi-colour led.

Would someone be able to provide me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the circuit from the [other question:](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130999/low-battery-level-circuit-changing-trigger-level)

[image]

The LEDs are connected together on the positive side.  To make this circuit with a bi-color LED, you will need what is called a "common anode" LED.  It will have an internal circuit like this:

[image]

That matches what your transistor circuit needs.

Many bi-color LEDs are "common cathode." Like this:

[image]

That will **not** work with the given circuit.

Either use a common anode bi-color LED, or two separate LEDs.

To change the voltage where it switches colors, you must change the Zener diode.

For a 5V switch-over, you'll want a 4.3V Zener diode

Comment: Thanks for the info. JRE. I was unaware of common anode LEDs. I had only ever seen the common cathode ones. 

Given that i am operating at a lower voltage then the above. Do you think i need to change any of the resistor values? i was going to use a 240R in place of the 330R resistors but i wasn't sure if anything else would need to change, apart from the zener diode of course.

Comment: It'll still be plenty bright if you use the 330 ohm resistor.  Common cathode is more common than common anode.  You'll probably have to search for and specifically order common anode LEDs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide another possibility, with hysteresis included:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe8AbJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, adjust \$R_5\$ and \$R_6\$ to get the right hysteresis (too small and there won't be much of any at all, too large and the hysteresis might be too wide and the LEDs not bright enough. I'm just guessing here with the \$390\:\Omega\$ resistors. You may need to adjust them up to somewhat higher values (or perhaps just slightly lower.) You can move the voltage at which they switch by changing \$R_2\$, a little. Lowering \$R_2\$ moves the voltage threshold upward. Raising \$R_2\$ moves the voltage threshold down to lower voltages. (You could also play with \$R_1\$, instead.)

The ratio and absolute values for \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ are a guess of mine. But they may be close enough. Some will depend on the NPN BJTs you are using, too. But once you have it set up right, it will work consistently. No zeners required and the above circuit is targeted with typical BJTs and hysteresis near the value you said you wanted. (But BJTs and LEDs vary a bit. So some tinkering may help get it where you want it.)