# How do I make a battery indicator?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, diodes, zener

I want to make a battery indicator where there is only one red LED that would light up when the battery drops below a 3V.

Components I want to include in this circuit

-Transistor(BJT)(2N3904)

-Zener diode

pls tell me how do I built the circuit

Comment: why do you need to use a zener diode? ... it makes it sound like a schoolwork assignment

Comment: you build the circuit using a soldering iron and solder, and following a schematic diagram

Comment: If you use only those components you will just drain your battery.

Comment: "one red LED that would light up when the battery drops below a 3V" = battery discharges even more when battery is discharged. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Here you go... someone asked the question 6 years ago: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/130999/low-battery-level-circuit-changing-trigger-level

Comment: Zener diode is a bad choice.   Better to use a purpose-built comparator.

Comment: Of more interest would be one that lights up when the battery is dead